# Adding transition animations with Jquery Mobile on <div> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, jquery-mobile

may I remind you before answering that I'm a complete imbecile on Javascript.

I was provided a script to enable swipe navigation on my Jquery Mobile Site by Padilicious. It works by placing these functions, as I understand, on a div tag:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="swipeBox" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'swipeBox');"  ontouchend="touchEnd(event);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
```

Now my problem is that data-transition on Jquery Mobile only works on  tags or buttons. How do I add data-transition, or at least entrance and exit transitions, on a  tag?

If you guys also need the JS for the swipe navigation script, here it is:

```
// TOUCH-EVENTS SINGLE-FINGER SWIPE-SENSING JAVASCRIPT
        // Courtesy of PADILICIOUS.COM and MACOSXAUTOMATION.COM

        // this script can be used with one or more page elements to perform actions based on them being swiped with a single finger

        var triggerElementID = null; // this variable is used to identity the triggering element
        var fingerCount = 0;
        var startX = 0;
        var startY = 0;
        var curX = 0;
        var curY = 0;
        var deltaX = 0;
        var deltaY = 0;
        var horzDiff = 0;
        var vertDiff = 0;
        var minLength = 72; // the shortest distance the user may swipe
        var swipeLength = 0;
        var swipeAngle = null;
        var swipeDirection = null;

        // The 4 Touch Event Handlers

        // NOTE: the touchStart handler should also receive the ID of the triggering element
        // make sure its ID is passed in the event call placed in the element declaration, like:
        // <div id="picture-frame" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'picture-frame');"  ontouchend="touchEnd(event);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);">

        function touchStart(event,passedName) {
            // disable the standard ability to select the touched object
            event.preventDefault();
            // get the total number of fingers touching the screen
            fingerCount = event.touches.length;
            // since we're looking for a swipe (single finger) and not a gesture (multiple fingers),
            // check that only one finger was used
            if ( fingerCount == 1 ) {
                // get the coordinates of the touch
                startX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                startY = event.touches[0].pageY;
                // store the triggering element ID
                triggerElementID = passedName;
            } else {
                // more than one finger touched so cancel
                touchCancel(event);
            }
        }

        function touchMove(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
                curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
            } else {
                touchCancel(event);
            }
        }

        function touchEnd(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // check to see if more than one finger was used and that there is an ending coordinate
            if ( fingerCount == 1 && curX != 0 ) {
                // use the Distance Formula to determine the length of the swipe
                swipeLength = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(curX - startX,2) + Math.pow(curY - startY,2)));
                // if the user swiped more than the minimum length, perform the appropriate action
                if ( swipeLength >= minLength ) {
                    caluculateAngle();
                    determineSwipeDirection();
                    processingRoutine();
                    touchCancel(event); // reset the variables
                } else {
                    touchCancel(event);
                }   
            } else {
                touchCancel(event);
            }
        }

        function touchCancel(event) {
            // reset the variables back to default values
            fingerCount = 0;
            startX = 0;
            startY = 0;
            curX = 0;
            curY = 0;
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = 0;
            horzDiff = 0;
            vertDiff = 0;
            swipeLength = 0;
            swipeAngle = null;
            swipeDirection = null;
            triggerElementID = null;
        }

        function caluculateAngle() {
            var X = startX-curX;
            var Y = curY-startY;
            var Z = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X,2)+Math.pow(Y,2))); //the distance - rounded - in pixels
            var r = Math.atan2(Y,X); //angle in radians (Cartesian system)
            swipeAngle = Math.round(r*180/Math.PI); //angle in degrees
            if ( swipeAngle < 0 ) { swipeAngle =  360 - Math.abs(swipeAngle); }
        }

        function determineSwipeDirection() {
            if ( (swipeAngle <= 45) && (swipeAngle >= 0) ) {
                swipeDirection = 'left';
            } else if ( (swipeAngle <= 360) && (swipeAngle >= 315) ) {
                swipeDirection = 'left';
            } else if ( (swipeAngle >= 135) && (swipeAngle <= 225) ) {
                swipeDirection = 'right';
            } else if ( (swipeAngle > 45) && (swipeAngle < 135) ) {
                swipeDirection = 'down';
            } else {
                swipeDirection = 'up';
            }
        }

        function processingRoutine() {
            var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
            if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'up' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'down' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            }

        }
```

Note that the following are the ones responsible for redirecting to another page:

```
function processingRoutine() {
            var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
            if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'up' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            } else if ( swipeDirection == 'down' ) {
                // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
                window.location.href = "gallery.html";
            }
```

My main agenda is only on adding a sliding animations on page transitions. Doesn't matter on how I should do it. Thanks, Love ya!

Comment: I am not getting you.If Page1 go to Page2 there should be a slide animation?If Page2 go to Page3 there should be a slide animation?Is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because data-transition does not work on anything besides <a> tag.

Comment: Ok check my answer

Answer (score 0):

No need to write that much code.Try following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageOne">
 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  Page One
  <br>
  <a href="#pageTwo" data-transition="slide">Go to page Two</a> 
 </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pageTwo">
 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  Page Two
  <br>  
  <a href="#pageOne" data-transition="slide">Go to page One</a> 
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```